# How to transfer RDBMS data with multiple primary key into elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, database, elasticsearch

I'd like to transfer data from RDBMS to elasticsearch.

From MySQL data

```
+---------+-----------+
| col1    | col2      |
+---------+-----------+
| a       |      abc  |
| a       |      def  |
| a       |      ghi  |
| a       |      jkl  |
| a       |      mno  |
| b       |      pqr  |
| b       |      stu  |
| b       |      vwx  |
+---------+-----------+
```

to Elasticsearch Data

```
{
  "col1" : "a",
  "col2" : ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"]
}

{
  "col1" : "b",
  "col2" : ["pqr", "stu", "vwx"]
}
```

I'd like to put col1 as '_id'.

Is it possible by Logstash or any other transfer tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add exactly what you want as an _id in elasticsearch.
Logstash let you define it easily in the elasticsearch output with the [document_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id) param.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I just found out that col2 data is not stacked like "col2" : ["pqr", "stu", "vwx"]. Only one data remain. Any solution from Logstash output plugin?

Comment: I presume your use case is: You read the DB line by line and want to update the index.  It's not really easy.
At first you'll have to add the update param in the elastic search output.
And you'll need to use the elasticsearch FILTER to get the doc, update it in the logstash filters, then output it again and again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jaycreation and googling. I just found out how to import data from MySQL to EL.
First of all, conf file will be like this.

```json
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "dbname:port/dev_new_areyousick_algorithm?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "unix_ts_in_secs"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    schedule => "*/10 * * * * *"
    #statement => "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(update_dt) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM tb_hospinfo_review WHERE update_dt < NOW() ORDER BY update_dt ASC"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM table_name"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "col1" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
    remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp"]
  }
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{col1}"
    code => "
      map['col1'] ||= event.get('col1')
      map['col2s'] ||= []
      map['col2s'] << {'col2' => event.get('col2')}
      event.cancel()
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 3
  }

}
output {
  # stdout { codec =>  "rubydebug"}
  elasticsearch {
      index => "keyword_table"
      document_id => "%{col1}"
  }
}
```

More formal example is shown in
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example4

and most important thing is(in my term)
the way to execute on CLI.

At first, I put the line like

```
sudo ./logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash -f ./logstash-conf.conf
```

but some data was imported but some data was not.

And I've just realized that Logstash is parallel processing pipelines.
In filter plugin, 'aggregate' call is unique to the pipelines.
So I've added -w 1 at the end of the CLI line and it works!!